# Prove the following about infinimum

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

The distance $d(x_0,A)$ between a point $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and a non-empty set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is $d(x_0,A) = \inf\limits_{x \in A}\lVert x_0 - x\rVert $.
If $A$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $d(x_0,A) = 0$ if and only if $x \in A$.

The direction beginning with $x \in A$ is trivial. The other direction I'm having trouble with. I'm not sure how to use the fact that $A$ is a closed subset.

Comment: Suppose $\inf_{x\in A}||x_0-x||=0$, can you use this to find a sequence $(a_n)_n\in A$ such that $a_n\to x_0$? What can you then tell about $x$ based on this fact and the closedness of $A$?

Comment: What exactly is the $\epsilon$ definition of $inf_{x \in A}||x_0 - x||$. The $\epsilon$ definition I have seen is in $\mathbb{R}$. But this is in $\mathbb{R^n}$ and involves the norm. So I'm a bit confused on how to convert this into an epsilon statement.

Comment: Once you take the norm, you automatically land in $\mathbb{R}$ again. So you can use the definition of $\inf$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Oh you're right. Yeah the notation kinda confused me at first.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $\inf\{\|x_0-x\| : x \in A\} = 0$ means that for all $\varepsilon>0$ we can find $x_\varepsilon \in A$ such that $\|x_0-x_\varepsilon\| < \varepsilon$, otherwise there exists an $\varepsilon_0 > 0$ such that $\|x_0-x\| \geq \varepsilon_0$ for every $x \in A$, that is, there exists an $\varepsilon_0 > 0$ which is an upper bound of $\{\|x_0-x\| : x \in A\}$, and then $\inf\{\|x_0-x\| : x \in A\} > 0$.

Hence, $d(x_0,A) = 0$ means that for all $\varepsilon>0$ we have $B(x_0,\varepsilon) \cap A \neq \varnothing$, i.e. $x_0 \in \overline A = A$.

Comment: I understand your solution, but I'm trying to solve this problem using the characterization of closed sets containing all their limit points.